# Kubuntu microphone volume level keeps going down

Tags: kde, microphone

I'm using KDE and am using Skype and a Java program (Runescape Client) at the same time. I have the mixer open and the volume of my mic keeps going down automatically. I really have no idea what is going on ... is there any way I can fix this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Open Skype > Options > Sound Devices, and uncheck the box that says "Allow Skype to automatically adjust my mixer levels".

I find Skype never does a very good job of regulating this (at least it never did when I used this option on my previous computer, running OS X).

Comment: No worries! Glad I could help.

Comment: This also works in Zoom: In `Settings > Audio`, uncheck "Automatically adjust microphone volume"