# microphone level keeps going up and down

Tags: 18.04, sound, microphone, zoom-meeting

I am on 18.04.5 LTS (Bionic Beaver) on a Dell XPS 13 computer using a Jabra headset and when I am on Zoom calls sometimes the input level goes all the way down and people can no longer hear me. I don't think I am pressing anything to cause this.

Answer (score 1):

This question helped me [Kubuntu microphone volume level keeps going down](https://askubuntu.com/questions/253277/kubuntu-microphone-volume-level-keeps-going-down) . Zoom has the same automatic adjustment feature. I turned it off.